# Is kinetic energy the same as other types of energy?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, energy, dimensional-analysis

I think we can all agree on the following in classical mechanics:
$$
\textrm{Energy in Joules}=\frac{kg_a\times m_{a1}\times m_{a2}}{s_{a1}\times s_{a2}}\neq \frac{kg_b\times m_{b1}\times m_{b2}}{2\times s_{b1}\times s_{b2}}=\textrm{Kinetic Energy in Joules}
$$
For all of the "this is a duplicate" people: no one has taken an SI base unit approach to define the difference in definitions.
I put the subscripts there and used no exponents to help us distinguish distinct properties in the discussion.
I understand that you can keep the statement true by replacing the not equal to symbol for the approximation or proportional symbols, but I think one half is too far off. Also, "because you don't know calculus" is not a good reason to claim the not equal to symbol should be replaced for the equal to symbol.   The difference has to be in the definitions of the variables or the words on the outsides.

Here is an example to discuss:
Suppose I have a shot put ball that has a mass of 4 kilograms resting in my hand with no velocity.
I then through the ball with a 3 second long 2 meter motion to give it a instantaneous velocity of 13 meters per second.
Am I wrong in any of the following?
kg_a = kg_b = 4
m_a1 = m_a2 = m_b1 = m_b2 = 13
s_a1 = s_a2 = s_b1 = s_b2 = 1
Energy in Joules = 676 Joules != Kinetic Energy in Joules = 338 Joules.

Comment: There is a lot of confusing stuff written here. If you're holding 4kg ball in your hand it has no kinetic energy. If you then throw it upwards with a velocity of 13m/s it will have a kinetic energy of $KE=\frac{1}{2}mv^2$. It will then slowly lose that kinetic energy as it is transferred into gravitational potential energy until it comes to a stop at which point it will again have zero kinetic energy.

Comment: Your equations are a little confusing. You're using k for m, m for s, and s for t. Is this a mechanics version of [Who's on First?](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Who%27s_on_First%3F) ;)

Comment: Your notation is extremely confusing, such as using $m$ for distance and $s$ for time. (Yes, I see why you chose these, but nobody does this.)

Comment: Sorry for not being explicit about the symbols. They are SI base units. kg - kilograms, m - meters, s - seconds. Also I am referring to the energy the ball has when it leaves my hand.

Comment: Now that the bizarre notation is behind us, I have no idea what you are trying to do so I have voted to close as unclear.

Comment: It appears that the whole point of this question is that you think the answer should be $mv^2$, because that has the right units. But that's not how it works. $1/2$ doesn't have any units either, so looking at the units alone can't tell you whether the answer is $mv^2$ or $mv^2/2$. You actually have to think about it.

Comment: As another example of this, suppose I drive in a circle at 30 miles per hour for 2 hours. How far have I gotten? Well, it must be (30 miles per hour) * (2 hours) = 60 miles, right? But no, if I drove in a circle, then I didn't actually get anywhere at all. You can't just blindly multiply things together without thinking about the situation.

Comment: *I think we can all agree on the following* Definitely not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have noticed that if you take the mass of an object and multiply it by its speed squared, you get something with units of energy. And while this is true, why do you say this is "the" energy of the object? It's just not. The kinetic energy is $(1/2)mv^2$, and there are other forms of energy, with different formulas.

What you're doing is essentially called dimensional analysis, and it's a very useful thing: some times, just by looking at the units of the quantities involved, you can figure out the general shape of the formula you're looking for; in this case, you know that $mv^2$ gives you something with units of energy. But dimensional analysis can't tell you whether it's $mv^2$, $mv^2/2$, $3mv^2$, or any other numerical factor. That has to come from somewhere else.

Comment: Thank you so much. I did not know what dimensional analysis was.

Answer (score 0):

The reason we choose $\frac12 m v^2$ instead of $mv^2$ as kinetic energy is simply that this is the only one which satisfies the conservation of energy
$$
\frac12mv^2+V(x) = const
$$

While on the other hand
$$
mv^2+V(x) = \frac12 m v^2 \neq const
$$

Energy only exhibits itself when it **transfers** from one object to another, or **converts** to other forms of energy.

To see if $mv^2$ works, try to convert it to another form of energy whose formula you know. For example, does equal amount of $(mv^2)_{loss}$ means equal amount of $(mgh)_{gain}$? This comes down to verifying
$$
mv_{final}^2-mv_{initial}^2 = mgh_{final}-mgh_{initial} \\
v_{final}^2-v_{initial}^2 = g(h_{final}-h_{initial})
$$

You might have learned in your kinetics course that
$$
v_{final}^2-v_{initial}^2 = 2g(h_{final}-h_{initial})
$$
And now you can see that the form you proposed contradicts with the rules of kinetics and its experiments. A quick remedy would be to divide both sides by 2:
$$
\frac12 v_{final}^2- \frac12 v_{initial}^2 = g(h_{final}-h_{initial})
$$
Multiply $m$ back, And you have arrived at the definition of kinetic energy yourself, which is $\frac12 m v^2$.